# matchbox- keyboard , only with numbers

Tags: keyboard, raspberry-pi

i just downloaded the matchbox-keyboard - module, which works absolute fine for me. The problem is, that I only need the numbers (0-9) of the keyboard. Is there a possibility remove all the other Buttons?

thanks for your help

Comment: okay i managed it by using a given layout :

matchbox-keyboard -s 50 numpad-small